# how to write eprom data into USB Device by using USB Host in an embedded system?

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-host

I want to write AT24C64D EEPROM data  to USB Device i.e (pen drive)
using USB Host i.e (STM32L100RCT6 MCU).
eeprom is interfaced with STM32L100RCT6  via I2C and this STM32L100RCT6  has USB device controller so I want to configure STM32L100RCT6 as USB host so that I can write the content of my eeprom into the USB Device i.e (pen Drive) so If anyone knows then help will be appreciate .
thank you !!!

Answer (score 6):

You can't. From [the STM32L100RC datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l100rc.pdf):

> **3.15.4 Universal serial bus (USB)**
>
> The STM32L100RC device embeds a USB device peripheral compatible with the USB full-speed 12 Mbit/s. […]

The STM32L100RC only has a USB *device* peripheral, not a host controller. It cannot operate as a USB host.

ST has a number of other microcontrollers which do support USB host operation. Take a close look at their parts catalog to find something more appropriate for your needs.